# Why do I keep on getting errors like Error Code 1146 in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, sql-insert, create-table

I keep on getting 1146 Error Code: 1146. Table 'world.itemsintransactions' doesn't exist, and before I kept on getting many other diffferent error codes that I eventually fix only to move onto another error code. Please bear in mind this is my first MySQL assignment, never used MySQL before this assignment, so apologies if I have missed out on something very obvious!

Here is my code...

```
Create DATABASE CS_Store;
USE CS_Store;

CREATE TABLE customers (
    birth_day date,
    first_name VARCHAR(20),
    last_name VARCHAR(20),
    c_id VARCHAR(20),
    CONSTRAINT PK_Customers PRIMARY KEY (c_id));
INSERT INTO customers (birth_day, first_name, last_name, c_id) VALUES ('1993-07-11','Victor','Davis',1);
INSERT INTO customers (birth_day, first_name, last_name, c_id) VALUES ('2001-03-28','Katarina','Williams',2);
INSERT INTO customers (birth_day, first_name, last_name, c_id) VALUES ('1965-12-11','David','Jones',3);
INSERT INTO customers (birth_day, first_name, last_name, c_id) VALUES ('1980-10-10','Evelyn','Lee',4);


CREATE TABLE employees (
    birth_day date,
    first_name VARCHAR(20),
    last_name VARCHAR(20),
    e_id int,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Employees PRIMARY KEY (e_id)
);
INSERT INTO employees (birth_day, first_name, last_name, e_id) VALUES ('1983-09-02','David','Smith',1);
INSERT INTO employees (birth_day, first_name, last_name, e_id) VALUES ('1990-07-23','Olivia','Brown',2);
INSERT INTO employees (birth_day, first_name, last_name, e_id) VALUES ('1973-05-11','David','Johnson',3);
INSERT INTO employees (birth_day, first_name, last_name, e_id) VALUES ('1999-11-21','Mia','Taylor',4);

CREATE TABLE transactions (
    e_id int,
    c_id int,
    date date,
    t_id int,
    CONSTRAINT PK_transactions PRIMARY KEY (t_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (e_id) REFERENCES employees(e_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (c_id) REFERENCES customers(c_id)
);
INSERT INTO transactions (e_id, c_id, date, t_id) VALUES (1,1,'2020-8-11',1);
INSERT INTO transactions (e_id, c_id, date, t_id) VALUES (3,1,'2020-8-15',2);
INSERT INTO transactions (e_id, c_id, date, t_id) VALUES (1,4,'2020-9-01',3);
INSERT INTO transactions (e_id, c_id, date, t_id) VALUES (2,2,'2020-9-07',4);
INSERT INTO transactions (e_id, c_id, date, t_id) VALUES (4,3,'2020-9-07',5);


CREATE TABLE items (
    amount int,
    price_for_each int,
    name VARCHAR(20),
    CONSTRAINT PK_items PRIMARY KEY (name)
);
INSERT INTO items (price_for_each, amount, name) VALUES (110,22,'2lof milk');
INSERT INTO items (price_for_each, amount, name) VALUES (99,30,'6 cans of lemonade');
INSERT INTO items (price_for_each, amount, name) VALUES (150,20,'Pack of butter');
INSERT INTO items (price_for_each, amount, name) VALUES (450,13,'Roast chicken');
INSERT INTO items (price_for_each, amount, name) VALUES (99,30,'Pack of rice');
INSERT INTO items (price_for_each, amount, name) VALUES (20,50,'Banana');
INSERT INTO items (price_for_each, amount, name) VALUES (200,30,'3kg sugar');
INSERT INTO items (price_for_each, amount, name) VALUES (150,15,'Toast bread');
INSERT INTO items (price_for_each, amount, name) VALUES (150,18,'Earl Grey tea');

CREATE TABLE promotions (
    discount int,
    p_id int,
    CONSTRAINT PK_promotions PRIMARY KEY (p_id)
);
INSERT INTO promotions (discount, p_id) VALUES (99,1);
INSERT INTO promotions (discount, p_id) VALUES (200,2);
INSERT INTO promotions (discount, p_id) VALUES (150,3);
INSERT INTO promotions (discount, p_id) VALUES (150,4);

CREATE TABLE itemsinpromotions (
    name VARCHAR(20),
    p_id int,
    amount int,
    FOREIGN KEY (name) REFERENCES items(name),
    FOREIGN KEY (p_id) REFERENCES promotions(p_id)
);
INSERT INTO itemsinpromotions (name, p_id, amount) VALUES ('6 cans of lemonade',1,2);
INSERT INTO itemsinpromotions (name, p_id, amount) VALUES ('Roast chicken',2,1);
INSERT INTO itemsinpromotions (name, p_id, amount) VALUES ('Pack of rice',2,1);
INSERT INTO itemsinpromotions (name, p_id, amount) VALUES ('Pack of butter',3,1);
INSERT INTO itemsinpromotions (name, p_id, amount) VALUES ('Toast bread',3,2);
INSERT INTO itemsinpromotions (name, p_id, amount) VALUES ('2lof milk',4,2);
INSERT INTO itemsinpromotions (name, p_id, amount) VALUES ('Banana',4,3);
INSERT INTO itemsinpromotions (name, p_id, amount) VALUES ('3kg sugar',4,2);

CREATE TABLE itemsintransactions (
    name VARCHAR(20),
    t_id int,
    amount int,
    FOREIGN KEY (name) REFERENCES items(name),
    FOREIGN KEY (t_id) REFERENCES transactions(t_id)
);
INSERT INTO itemsintransactions (name, t_id, amount) VALUES('6 cans of lemonade',1,1);
INSERT INTO itemsintransactions (name, t_id, amount) VALUES ('Roast chicken',1,1);
INSERT INTO itemsintransactions (name, t_id, amount) VALUES ('Pack of butter',1,1);
INSERT INTO itemsintransactions (name, t_id, amount) VALUES ('Toast bread',1,1);
INSERT INTO itemsintransactions (name, t_id, amount) VALUES ('2lof milk',1,2);
INSERT INTO itemsintransactions (name, t_id, amount) VALUES ('Banana',1,3);
INSERT INTO itemsintransactions (name, t_id, amount) VALUES ('3kg sugar',1,1);
INSERT INTO itemsintransactions (name, t_id, amount) VALUES ('6 cans of lemonade',2,5);
INSERT INTO itemsintransactions (name, t_id, amount) VALUES ('Pack of rice',2,1);
INSERT INTO itemsintransactions (name, t_id, amount) VALUES ('6 cans of lemonade',3,3);
INSERT INTO itemsintransactions (name, t_id, amount) VALUES ('Roast chicken',3,2);
INSERT INTO itemsintransactions (name, t_id, amount) VALUES ('Pack of rice',3,1);
INSERT INTO itemsintransactions (name, t_id, amount) VALUES ('Pack of butter',3,1);
INSERT INTO itemsintransactions (name, t_id, amount) VALUES ('2lof milk',4,5);
INSERT INTO itemsintransactions (name, t_id, amount) VALUES ('Banana',4,20);
INSERT INTO itemsintransactions (name, t_id, amount) VALUES ('3kg sugar',4,8);
INSERT INTO itemsintransactions (name, t_id, amount) VALUES ('6 cans of lemonade',5,10);
INSERT INTO itemsintransactions (name, t_id, amount) VALUES ('Roast chicken',5,10);
INSERT INTO itemsintransactions (name, t_id, amount) VALUES ('Pack of rice',5,10);
INSERT INTO itemsintransactions (name, t_id, amount) VALUES ('Pack of butter',5,10);
INSERT INTO itemsintransactions (name, t_id, amount) VALUES ('Toast bread',5,10);
INSERT INTO itemsintransactions (name, t_id, amount) VALUES ('2lof milk',5,10);
INSERT INTO itemsintransactions (name, t_id, amount) VALUES ('Banana',5,10);
INSERT INTO itemsintransactions (name, t_id, amount) VALUES ('3kg sugar',5,10);
INSERT INTO itemsintransactions (name, t_id, amount) VALUES ('Earl Grey tea',5,10);



CREATE VIEW DavidSoldTo AS 
    SELECT birth_day, first_name, last_name
    FROM customers
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Transactions WHERE e_id=1)
    ORDER BY birth_day
;

CREATE VIEW PeopleInShop AS 
    SELECT DISTINCT birth_day, first_name, last_name
    FROM Employees
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT birth_day, first_name, last_name
    FROM Customers
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Transactions WHERE date=2020-9-07)
    ORDER BY birth_day
;


CREATE VIEW ItemsLeft AS 
    SELECT amount AS amount_left, name
    FROM Items
    WHERE amount_left NOT IN (SELECT COUNT(t_id) FROM Transactions)
    GROUP BY name
;
    
    
    -- Not yet completed
CREATE VIEW PromotionItemsSatisfiedByTransactions AS
    SELECT name, p_id, COUNT(t_id) AS number_of_times
    FROM Promotions NATURAL JOIN Transactions
    SELECT number_of_times 
    WHERE number_of_times >= 1;c_id
```

Comment: What does this have to do with SQL Server?

Comment: apologies, it was put there automatically and i forgot to delete it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the error related to the schema name, that was explained by @ysth, there is another issue with your code. Consider these table declarations:

```
create table customers (
    birth_day date,
    first_name varchar(20),
    last_name varchar(20),
    c_id varchar(20),
    constraint pk_customers primary key (c_id)
);

create table transactions (
    e_id int,
    c_id int,
    date date,
    t_id int,
    constraint pk_transactions primary key (t_id),
    foreign key (e_id) references employees(e_id),
    foreign key (c_id) references customers(c_id)
);
```

The problem is that `customers(c_id)` is of datatype `varchar(20)`, while referencing column `transactions(c_id)` is `int`. Because of that, the foreign key constraint creation fails, as does the creation of table `transactions`. The missing table propagates error through out the rest of the script.

Fix one of the datatype so they are identical. I would expect something called `..._id` to be `int`. Then, the whole script should just work.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8bf60761a7bdcaa6acc754f91ce6a01f)**

Answer (score 0):

A mysql database server can have several databases, like the `CS_Store`.  When accessing a database other than the currently `USE`'d one, you qualify table names with the database name.  `world.itemsintransactions` is a reference to the `itemsintransactions` table in the `world` database, which you don't seem to be actually creating.  Perhaps your instructions intend you to be using `world` instead of `CS_Store`?